# No Window Options in Cairo Dock

Tags: 12.04, cairo-dock

I'm not even sure how to describe this properly.  I'm running Cairo Dock on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I've noticed that I no longer have the top bar of my windows.  I mean, I have the bar itself, but it's empty aside from the name of the window and the close / resize boxes.  For instance, a simple Nautilus window would have, when you move the cursor to the top bar, a list of options such as View / Edit  etc.   I have nothing like that for any window or application.  It's just solid black.  This is a huge problem and I'm not sure what the issue is.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Cairo Dock has no options in the bar. To change anything just right-click on the dock itself and choose cairo and sub-menus will appear. Iam running Cairo too. Except for cairo dock i find that every other applications i find it has the View , Edit and so on options. Are you sure that other than Cairo application the other applications like Libre- Office are having this problem. Please be specific.

Comment: I have the problem in literally every application.  Nautilus, Chrome, even Pan Newsreader.  If I want to do something such as UnDoing a file move in Nautilus or editing server info in Pan, I have to open Compiz-Config, enable Unity,wait for Unity to load, and then the options appear in the bar at the top of the Unity screen.

Answer (score 0):

You will see only Chrome or whatever applications you open. But when you hover your mouse over to the bar you will see the options for the applications that is cuurently active. I say just hover your mouse over to the bar while the Window is still active. In worst case scenario you can still use HUD by pressing Alt key when the application is active .Hope this helps.Best of luck buddy

Comment: Actually hovering does nothing at all.  Neither does pressing the Alt key.  If it weren't for the fact that I have the window resize / close boxes I would swear that the top bar is somehow hidden or pushed up over the top of the visible screen.